# MFC: How to set different Icons in Titlebar and Taskbar

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm working on an big legacy MFC application in Visual Studio 2017.
I want to set a different icon in the titlebar than in the taskbar.
I can change the Icon like that:

```
HICON hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon( IDI_LOGO_WHITE );
SetIcon( hIcon, FALSE );
```

But it changes in the title and taskbar. Is there a way to change just the Icon in the titlebar?
eg. The Visual Studio 2017 icon in darkmode is white in the titlebar and purple in the taskbar.

Comment: I'm not aware of any software that does this.

Comment: Does this work?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18493442/how-to-change-the-icon-in-taskbar-using-windows-api

Comment: That doesn't work because by default the Icon in the taskbar is the same as in the titlebar. If I try the Solution you linked the Icon gets changed in both places.